# Changing shape of MNIST for tensorflow CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network, mnist

I have a model which requires the training images to be of shape [None, 28, 28, 1] but the MNIST images are [784,]. How do I change the shape of all images in training and test set to the required shape?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Using `numpy.reshape`

Comment: By default, MNIST images are of the size (28,28).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use either `numpy` or `tensorflow` itself to reshape your input. For example, if your input tensor is of shape `(784,)`, you can reshape it like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
reshaped_tensor = tf.reshape(input_tensor, [28,28,1])
```

Comment: If your batch size is larger than 1, you might have to reshape your tensor to be [-1,28,28,1] instead so that the first axis is the length of your batch size.